# HTML/CSS. При статусе :hover должен отображаться другой рисунок

Tags: html, css

Коллеги прошу помочь, создал кнопку, ну рисунок как кнопку буду использовать. При наведение на рисунок должна появляться другой рисунок

HTML code:

```
<a href="test" class="button1"><img src="/static/button1.bmp"></a>
```

CSS code:

```
.button1: hover {

    background: url('/static/button2.bmp');
}
```

Comment: А фласк тут причем? Вопроос чисто по хтмл-ксс, вроде. Скорее всего так происходит, тк картинка сверху перекрывает бэкграунд. Попробуйте сделать ссылку не как изображение, а как див с одним бэкграундом, а при наведении бэкграунд меняется.

Comment: Либо же можете просто заменять рисунок через js.

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил вставить изображения в html.
Такой способ хороший, потому что изображения загружаются, когда вы заходите на страницу, так как они находятся в разметке

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

img {
  display: block;
}

.btn {
  user-select: none;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  background-color: pink;
  font-size: 10vw;
  padding: 1vw 2vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid pink;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-property: background-color, border-color, color;
  z-index: 1;
}

.btn__img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.btn__main {
  z-index: 3;
  position: relative;
}

.btn__img__container {
  /* Все .btn__img__container прозрачны по умолчанию */
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

/* Первый .btn__img__container будет непрозрачным */
.btn__secondary > .btn__img__container:first-child {
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn__img__container::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  /* Прозрачный цвет, который ложится на изображение для затемнения, поставьте rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), чтобы не было затемнения */
}

.btn:hover {
  border-color: black;
  background-color: white;
  color: red;
}

/* Второй .btn__img__container при наведении будет непрозрачным, перекроет первый .btn__img__container, который тоже непрозрачный */
.btn:hover .btn__secondary > .btn__img__container:last-child {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn">
  <div class="btn__main">
    Купи меня
  </div>
  <div class="btn__secondary">
    <div class="btn__img__container">
      <img class="btn__img" src="https://picsum.photos/1000/300">
    </div>
    <div class="btn__img__container">
      <img class="btn__img" src="https://picsum.photos/1200/200">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```